# Excel VBA: "Next Without For" Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting the "next without for" error. I checked other questions on this and looked for any open if statements or loops in my code, but could find none. I'm need an extra set of eyes to catch my error here.

I am trying to loop through this code and advance the torque value 3 times each times it gets to the 30th i.

```
'This is Holzer's method for finding the torsional natural frequency

Option Explicit


Sub TorsionalVibrationAnalysis_()
    Dim n As Integer 'position along stucture
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim i As Long 'frequency to be used
    Dim j As Variant 'moment of inertia
    Dim k As Variant 'stiffness
    Dim theta As Long 'angular displacement
    Dim torque As ListRow 'torque
    Dim lambda As Long 'ListRow 'omega^2
    Dim w As Variant
    Dim s As Long

'equations relating the displacement and torque


n = 1
Set j = Range("d2:f2").Value 'Range("d2:f2").Value
Set k = Range("d3:f3").Value
    'initial value
Set w = Range("B1:B30").Value

For i = 1 To 30

     'start at 40 and increment frequency by 20
    w = 40 + (i - 1) * 20

    lambda = w ^ 2

    theta = 1

    s = 1
    Do While i = 30 & s <= 3

        torque = lambda * j(1, s)

        s = s + 1

    End

    m = n + 1


    theta = theta - torque(i, n) / k(n)

    torque(i, m) = torque(i, n) + lambda * j(m) * theta

    If m = 4 & i < 30 Then

        w(i) = 40 + (i - 1) * 20

        lambda = w(i) ^ 2

        ElseIf m = 4 & i >= 30 Then

        Cells([d], [5+i]).display (i)
        Cells([e], [5+i]).display (theta)
        Cells([f], [5+i]).display (torque)

        Else

     End If

     If m <> 4 Then

        n = n + 1

     End If


Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That lonely `End` should be `Loop`

Comment: It's because of your `Do While` . It should end with a `Loop` not an `End`

Comment: All, the replacing end with a loop worked!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to terminate your `While` with an `End` instead of `Loop`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `End` to `Loop` in your `Do While` loop. I think you are terming the loop when you hit that `End`

Answer (score 0):

Proper indentation makes the problem rather apparent.

You have:

```
For i = 1 To 30
    '...
    Do While i = 30 & s <= 3
        '...    
    End

    '...

    If m = 4 & i < 30 Then

        '...

        ElseIf m = 4 & i >= 30 Then

        '...

        Else

     End If

     If m <> 4 Then

        '...

     End If

Next i
```

But run it through [Rubberduck's *Smart Indenter*](http://rubberduckvba.com/indenter) and you get:

```
For i = 1 To 30
    '...
    Do While i = 30 & s <= 3
        '...
        End

        '...

        If m = 4 & i < 30 Then

            '...

        ElseIf m = 4 & i >= 30 Then

            '...

        Else

        End If

        If m <> 4 Then

            '...

        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Notice how the `End` other answers are pointing out, is clearly not delimiting the `Do While` loop.

The `Next i` is inside the `Do While` block, which isn't terminated - when the VBA compiler encounters that `Next i`, it doesn't know how it could possibly relate to any previously encountered `For` statement, and thus issues a "Next without For" compile error.

Use an indenter.